# Python package: How to exclude all of the subdirectories in a directory

Tags: python, package

When I create a pypi package, I want to exclude all of the files and directories in a folder. For example:

```
my_package
   |-setup.py
   |-MANIFEST.in
   |-folder_to_exclude
        |-subfolder1
        |-subfolder2
```

In MANIFEST.in, I set

```
prune folder_to_exclude/*
recursive-exclude folder_to_exclude *
```

However, when I packaged it, only the files directly in the ''folder_to_exclude'' were excluded. The subfolders ''subfolder1'' and ''subfolder2'' and their files were still included.

Could someone please help me with this?